# Read csv file into dictionary in a certain format

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to read .csv file into dictionary in a certain format. Below is the reproducible format for the dataframe.

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [['fac1', 1,11], ['fac1', 2,12], ['fac1',3,13],['fac2',1,8],['fac2',2,9],['fac2',3,20]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['facility', 'customer','distance'])

print(df)

Output
  facility  customer  distance
  fac1         1        11
  fac1         2        12
  fac1         3        13
  fac2         1         8
  fac2         2         9
  fac2         3        20
```

I want to read this into a dictionary in certain format below

```
{'Fac-1': {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10},
 'Fac-2': {1: 6, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 8},
 'Fac-3': {1: 9, 2: 7, 3: 4, 4: 3, 5: 4}}
```

Comment: Explain the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this :

```
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["facility", "customer", "distance"])

dict = {
    k.replace("fac", "Fac_"): {c.customer: c.distance for _, c in v.iterrows()}
    for k, v in df.groupby(["facility"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to set the values inside dict to columns.
The external keys are `facility`, the dict internal keys are `customer`, and your values are `distance`. Have you tried something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

def dict_to_values(key, value):
    return len(value.keys())*[key], list(value.keys()), list(value.values())


d = {'Fac-1': {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10}, 'Fac-2': {1: 6, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 8},  'Fac-3': {1: 9, 2: 7, 3: 4, 4: 3, 5: 4}}

facility, customer, distance = [], [], [] 

for key, value in d.items():
    samples = dict_to_values(key, value)
    facility.extend(samples[0])
    customer.extend(samples[1])
    distance.extend(samples[2])

df = pd.DataFrame({'facility': facility, 'customer': customer, 'distance': distance})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   facility  customer  distance
0     Fac-1         1         4
1     Fac-1         2         5
2     Fac-1         3         6
3     Fac-1         4         8
4     Fac-1         5        10
5     Fac-2         1         6
6     Fac-2         2         4
7     Fac-2         3         3
8     Fac-2         4         5
9     Fac-2         5         8
10    Fac-3         1         9
11    Fac-3         2         7
12    Fac-3         3         4
13    Fac-3         4         3
14    Fac-3         5         4
```